# Viability of using "CMT" touchpad drivers on desktop

Tags: drivers, touchpad

There has been a project that I've seen used in Crouton on chromebooks to get dual booted Linux installations to work well with the touchpad on the chromebook with things like smooth, inertial, pixel perfect scrolling and smooth cursor movement. I've used it on a chromebook and it works perfectly, as well as when I connect an external touchpad to my chromebook (in this case the Logitech t650.) my question is, is it possible to install it on a desktop and get similar performance on an all-ubuntu system or will I just royally mess things up?

Here's a link to the Github for the driver: https://github.com/hugegreenbug/xf86-input-cmt

Answer (score 1):

I found a PPA for Ubuntu with this driver, you could use this to test it, if something does go wrong, it is easy to remove from a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hugegreenbug/cmt
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xf86-input-cmt
sudo reboot
```

The PPA also contains the dependencies `libgestures` `libevdevc` so it should work out of the box.

If you face any issues, just remove the driver like this

```
sudo apt-get purge xf86-input-cmt
```

From what I can see this is tested and working on Chromebooks with Ubuntu, although not by me.

[Here is a link to the repository](https://launchpad.net/~hugegreenbug/+archive/ubuntu/cmt)